# Group by and count in List

Tags: c#

I have an List which is filled with ints, like this:

```
[0] 1
[1] 4
[2] 4
[3] 8
[4] 9
[5] 1
[6] 1
```

So basically random numbers in there, but the same number can occure multiple times in that list.

What i want is to group them by number, but that i can also tell how many times that number was in the list. So that i have a something like:

```
[0] 
  [number] 1
  [total] 3  // Occured 3 times in the list
[1]
  [number] 4
  [total] 2
[2]
  [number] 8
  [total] 1
[3]
  [number] 9
  [total] 1
```

Is there a fast/easy way to accomplish this? Or do i have the write out all sorts of loops and checks to construct something like this manually?

Comment: Use LINQ. Wait answers will be pouring in.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) and `Count`:

```
var numberGroups = numbers.GroupBy(i => i);
foreach(var grp in numberGroups)
{
    var number = grp.Key;
    var total  = grp.Count();
}
```

Here's another example which uses an anonymous type to store some informations. It also creates an array since it seems to be the desired result:

```
var numberGroups = numbers.GroupBy(i => i)
                   .Select(grp => new{
                       number  = grp.Key,
                       total   = grp.Count(),
                       average = grp.Average(),
                       minimum = grp.Min(),
                       maximum = grp.Max()
                   })
                   .ToArray();

foreach (var numInfo in numberGroups)
{
    var number = numInfo.number;
    // ...
    var maximum = numInfo.maximum;
}
```

Comment: Which type the numberGroups will get in this case?

Comment: @besworland: In the second example this is an array of an anonymous type which you can use as a normal class but only in the current method.

Comment: @besworland: If you want to use the result it somewhere else, you could create an instance of a custom class in the `Select` as i'm creating that anonymous type. Then you can also return the result from the method f.e. as `YourType[]` or as `Tuple<int,int>`.

Comment: I actually have one small problem. Hope you can help me out with that. I'm trying to let a function return the newly constructed 'Array'. That works fine, but when i try to access the properties then it gives me an error eventhough they are in there. http://i.imgur.com/KIKgJ.png --- Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @w00: I assume that you return an array of the anonymous type. As i've said, you should not do that. Instead you create an array of a custom type(create a new class with appropriate properties). Then you can initiulize the instances in the LINQ-Select. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: Ahh sorry, i didn't see that comment. I made a class and initialized it inside the Select, like you said. Everything works fine now! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
var result = numbers.GroupBy(n => n)
                    .Select(c => new { Key = c.Key, total = c.Count() });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of *all sorts of loops and checks*:

```
var items = new Dictionary<int,int>();
foreach(var number in numbers)
{
   if(items.ContainsKey(number))
      items[number]++;
   else
      items.Add(number, 1);
}
```

Just for reference anyway. I prefer the LINQ approach, but it's not really as bad of a problem as you may have believed.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
var result = from i in n 
group i by i into g
select new {g.Key, Count= g.Count()};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only the `GroupBy` method you could do it like this:

```
var itemsResult = numbers.GroupBy(i => i,
                                  i => i,
                                  (keys, numbersGrouped) =>
                                      new{
                                          number = numbersGrouped.FirstOrDefault(),
                                          total = numbersGrouped.Count()
                                      }
                                  );
```

It outperforms the `GroupBy + Select` method proposed by the others executing in less than a half of the time comparing to the other implementations.

You can check below the performance comparison:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0M2aKD

This is the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__) for the function used if you want to check how does it works

Answer (score 0):

Using Tims method from above with a Select rather than a foreach you could do:

```
var itemsByGroupWithCount = numbers.GroupBy(i => i)
                 .Select(item => new { 
                        Number = item.Key, 
                        Total = item.Count()});
```