# how do you take a string then organize the words in it with how many times the word occurs in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

ok I have no idea on how to do this and i have tried looking up how to do this but nothing good came up so ill ask it here. So what i am trying to do is:

```
string input = TextEditor.text;    <-- this is in windows form application and
The "TextEditor" is the textbox for input
```

i want to take the string (which is input from the texct box) then split it so each word is on every other line like so:

if input = "hi my name is is"

out put should be:

```
hi: 1
my: 1
name: 1
is: 2 <-- if the word is said it shouldn't be repeated.
```

could someone please help me? I am a true newbie and i am completely lost. I don't have any code yet because I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS!

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Linq [GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600151) and Count:

```
string inputText = "hi my name is is";

var words = inputText.Split(' ').ToList();

var wordGroups = words.GroupBy(w => w).Select(grp => new {
                                                Word  = grp.Key,
                                                Count   = grp.Count()
                                            });

string outputText = string.Join("\n", wordGroups.Select(g => string.Format("{0}:\t{1}", g.Word, g.Count)));
/*
hi:  1
my:  1
name:  1
is:  2
*/
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Split the input string into an array, then use that to build a dictionary. If the word is already in the dictionary, increment it. Otherwise add it with an initial value of 1.

```
    string input = TextEditor.text;
    string[] inputWords = input.Split(' ');
    Dictionary<string, int> wordCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (string word in inputWords)
    {
        if (wordCounts.ContainsKey(word))
        {
            wordCounts[word]++;
        }
        else
        {
            wordCounts.Add(word, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thankyou I will try this

Comment: FYI you are looking up the word in the dictionary twice. Once to check if the word is there and then to increase the count.